# Microsoft Translator API 3.0 to HTML

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

is it possible to use microsoft translator text api 3.0 and return html instead of json. Right now I can input html and it will be returned into the json like this:

**Input:**

```html
<div>hi</div>
```

**Output:**

[ { "translations": [ { "text": "
Ciao</div>", "to": "it" } ] } ]

---

**Desired result:**

**Input:**

```html
<div>hi</div>
```

**Output:**

```html
<div>Ciao</div>
```

Would really appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: Can you add more details about your API call please? Looks like you are missing a parameter

Answer (score 2):

In the `Translate` method of Microsoft Translator API 3.0, there is the following `textType` parameter:

[image]

By default, the API method is considering your text as plain text. Add this parameter with `html` value and the result will not drop the `<div>` like in your question